# Compiling Sass files in NetBeans without Maven - Valo theme not found

Tags: netbeans, sass, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-valo-theme

I'm trying to integrate some Vaadin7 tech into an existing non-Vaadin project (built using Ant/NetBeans).  I've managed to get a "Hello World" page to appear, but it currently has no theming.  I have the standard starting theme, "mytheme", which does nothing except import the built-in Valo theme.  I've install Sass, and configured the project to automatically compile Sass files on save.  When I edit a Sass file, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Ruby23\bin\sass.bat" "--cache-location" "C:\Users\archiem\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\sass-compiler" "C:\src\mywebapp\web\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\styles.scss" "C:\src\mywebapp\web\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\styles.css"
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../valo/valo.scss.
    on line 30 of C:/src/mywebapp/web/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss
    from line 1 of C:\src\mywebapp\web\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\styles.scss
Use --trace for backtrace.
Done.
```

`mytheme.scss` contains the line:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";
```

It's completely understandable that Sass can't find this file, because there is no "valo" folder in "themes".
There is a JAR called `vaadin-themes-7.7.6.jar`, containing the package `VAADIN.themes.valo`, I assume this is what Sass needs.  What is the best way to make this resource available to Sass?  How do other people manually compile the Sass files in order to make tweaks to Vaadin's built-in themes?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to make this resource available to Sass?

Add the vaadin-themes-7.x.y.jar to your classpath.

> How do other people manually compile the Sass files in order to make
>   tweaks to Vaadin's built-in themes?

They use IDE specific Vaadin plugin to compile the custom themes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the NetBeans Vaadin plugin seems to require the project to be Maven-based (which mine isn't!)